# How to receive user information when user is authenticated with Google Adwords OAuth

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm building a web application with the google adwords API (ASP.NET Client library v14.5.0).
I'm using the builtin OAuth libraries to authenticate a user. Everything is working fine, but now I want to get user information, such as emailaddress and name from the user thats logged in.

Does somebody knows how this works?

Thanks!

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

AdWords API doesn't provide this information, you could try getting the User profile information instead. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#userinfocall for details.

Comment: I tried to send multiple  scopes with the API client library:

Comment: I tried to send multiple scopes with the client Library (below) and that seems to work. When the user is redirected to 
google, the users must allow access to google adwords and userinfo email.

googleAdwordsUser.OAuthProvider = new AdsOAuthNetProvider("https://adwords-sandbox.google.com/api/adwords/ https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    oauth_callback_url,
    Session.SessionID);

But when I try to receive the userinfo with a HttpRequest I'm getting an error.

'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.'